# DELPHI. How to close the modal form just after calling another modal form

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

IN MDI application there is an opened modal form A. The form B is being shown modal from form A.
How can I close the modal form A just after calling modal form B?

Comment: you can try calling the FormA.Hide; it will hide the form but not close as if the FormB is a Child to FormA i think you cannot close a Parent.

Comment: Maybe using wizard would be better option here than using isolated but sequential modal forms ?

Comment: You cannot - the whole point of a modal form is that the user is obliged to complete it (i.e. provide a ModalResult) before proceeding.  If you find you are having to play tricks to make it behave differently then I suggest you need to revisit your design.

Comment: @Hugh:  The problem often isn't one of the user completing the 1st modal form or not, but rather, of logic in the 1st form needing to control which modal form is displayed next in sequence. While there are many ways to conrol that, often the requirement can arise well after the application's structure is defined, and without the luxury of being able to revisit structural decisions...until the next major version, etc.

Comment: @Mark - sure.  I am answering this question in the context of another by the OP which shows, I think, that we are in the early stages of design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Hide the FormA before showing modal FormB. Then depending on ModalResult of FormB show or close the formA.

```
Hide; 
FormB.ShowModal; 
if FormB.ModalResult <> mrOK then Close;
```

ModalResult = mrOK means that Formb has opened a MDIchild form and was closed.

Answer (score 7):

Modality implies lifetime nesting. When one modal form opens another modal form, the first form needs to remain during the entire lifetime of the second modal form.

So, what you need to do is close the first modal form **before** you show the second modal form. That's a little tricky to do from inside the first modal form so it may be best to ask the main form for help. The main form can:

1. Call `Free` on the first modal form.
2. Create and show the second modal form.

If the first modal form needs to trigger this from one of its own event handlers, then the best way forward is for the first modal form to queue a message to the main form. For instance with `PostMessage` or `TThread.Queue`.

Comment: PostMessage(Self.Handle,wm_close,0,0); in the first modal form  closes the first modal form only after the second is closed;

Comment: @Avrob Yes. See the first paragraph of my answer.

Comment: @Arioch'The Depends on whether or not you get the lifetime of your forms right!

Comment: If the form is autocreated and not freed until the app exit, only being shown and hidden - what is wrong with that ?

Comment: Hmm, guess in this particular workflow the CPS-style of XE5 ShowModal overload could work better :-D

Comment: when I use Hide command for the first modal form then after the second modal form is closed the application stops respond to keyboard and mouse as there is an opened modal form.

Comment: @Avrob - because there is the chain of enabled/disabled windows and it goes something like `Application.Handle` -> `Application.MainForm.Handle` -> ... -> `FormA.Handle` -> `FormB.Handle`. By deleting/disabling/closing formA you just ensure that there is no gateway the events would reach formB, you just break the communication chain. David is right here, with VCL you have to close the FormA 1st and only then open the FormB. Maybe FormA.Release would do the trick BEFORE FormB.ShowModal - but that would be very fragile and actually abusing VCL API. Or upgrade to XE5 if CPS .SM is not FMX-only

Comment: @Avrob Read my answer again. Focus on the first paragraph.

Comment: ...i remember Andy was toying with offloading modal dialogs to fibers, but that is even yet more exotic and fragile trick :-D

Comment: I Hide the FormA before showing model FormB. Then depending on ModalResult of FormB show the formA again.

    Hide;
    FormB.ShowModal;
    if FormB.ModalResult <> mrOK then Show;

 ModalResult = mrOK means that Formb has opened a MDIchild form and was closed.

Comment: I am going cross-eyed just reading it.  No - too complicated.

Answer (score 3):

Setting a modally shown form's `ModalResult` property to a value other than `mrNone` will cause the form to be closed.

```
procedure TFormA.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowFormBModal;
  ModalResult := mrCancel; // this will close Form A if it's being shown modally
end;
```

Depending on your requirements, the actual value of `ModalResult` may depend on the modal result of Form B or other conditions.

Comment: The question wording sucks, but the discussion below Dvid's answer shows he got it right: the OP does not need A closed together with B after both forms were shown, he wants that A was closed when user would be working with B

Comment: @Arioch'The I think the question is clear, and so is the answer.

Comment: any text that talks about "calling a form" just cannot have a rigid sense thus cannot be clear :-)

Comment: @TOndrej: what does `ShowFormBModal` do?

Comment: ShowFormb depending on input values creates a MDIChid window or does nothing turning back.

Comment: @AlexSC Shows form B modally.

Comment: This solution to close Form A will wait until Form B is closed. I think OP want's to close Form A right away.

Comment: @NGLN What makes you think so? I don't see it anywhere in the question.

Comment: @TOndrej: It isn't in the question but in the comments under David's answer as Arioch 'The pointed out in his comment on your answer.

Comment: @MarjanVenema Right, it isn't in the question. It isn't in the comments, either, there he says only about hiding form A and showing it again, which seems unnecessary but he can do it with this approach, too.

Comment: Yeah, he is a bit cryptic but he does say 'hide A before showing B'... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Before closing the 1st modal form I would post a custom message to the application's mainform (or other), which would cause it to show the 2nd modal form. I prefer the idea of the 'owner' of both forms being in control.

PostMessage(Application.Mainform.Handle, DO_OPEN_2ND_MODALFORM, 0, 0);